# CSS flex and single digit

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, `flex` represents `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` combined. Default value is `0 1 auto`.

But what if `flex` has one single digit, like `flex: 1;`? Does that mean `flex-grow: 1`? What are the values for the rest two parameters?

Comment: So, why not use flex-grow: 1; directly instead of flex: 1; It's the same thing right?

Comment: So, `flex: 1` is interpreted as `1 1 0` and not `1 1 auto`?

Comment: Correct, according to the specs...though in IE it is `1 1 0px`. The dupe link has some more notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flex: 1` is the same as `flex: 1 1 0`

Google is your friend:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common

> flex: (positive-number)
>
> Makes the flex item flexible and sets the flex basis to zero,
>   resulting in an item that receives the specified proportion of the
>   free space in the flex container. If all items in the flex container
>   use this pattern, their sizes will be proportional to the specified
>   flex factor.Equivalent to flex:  1 0.